# R Shinyapp connects to server fine but on publishing driver is incorrect

Tags: sql, r, dns, shiny, odbc

So my Shinyapp works great locally connecting to my Azure Server housing my SQL database using this connection:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                  driver="SQL Server",
                  database="<db>",
                  UID="<user@db>",
                  PWD="<password>",
                  server="tcp:<user>.database.windows.net",
                  port=1433)
```

When publishing, I get this error:

```
nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 01000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]
    Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found
```

http://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html suggests to use `SQLServer` instead of `SQL Server` but the connection breaks down (both from locally and when publishing).

I've also tried the RODBC but this has not worked either.

I'm a bit stumped on what driver to use to make the connection work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!